# USB 3.0 Express Card for Linux

Tags: laptop, usb, linux

I need a **USB 3.0 Express Card with 2 Ports and 34mm width** that is **compatible with Linux**. Additional compatibility with Windows 10 would be great.

I already tried „[CSL - USB 3.0 Super Speed PCMCIA Express Card Karte (34mm / 2 Port / Windows 7 + Windows 8 kompatibel) für Notebook Laptop | USB Hub intern](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00C7NV69C/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1&pldnSite=1)“. But it has a „Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02)“ Chip and the current Linux kernel [doesn‘t support it. For more information please look here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=236806)

Comment: I have such a card with an uPD720202 chip and it works fine with kernel 4.18.4 (Self-compiled; maybe the driver is just not compiled with the pre-compiled distribution kernels?). My card is a 54mm, though, with optional external 5V power input socket between the two USB ports.

The uPD720202 chips are quite acceptable; I have read somewhere that FL1100 should be a bit better and that there is another chip which should be much worse; I do not remember where I read that.

Comment: [Here](https://thinkpad-forum.de/threads/180070-USB-3-0-ExpressCard-34mm-oder-54mm-f%C3%BCr-Linux) is also some discussion about such cards unter Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I found this: [USB 3.0 ExpressCard 34MM for GNU / Linux (TPE-USB3EXCD)](https://www.thinkpenguin.com/gnu-linux/usb-30-expresscard-34mm).

It's said to be compatible with Windows XP / Vista / 2000 / 7 / 8 and most recent linux distributions.

I haven't buyed and tested it yet, however.

I‘m thankful for more recommendations, however !